# Adicionar uma tag em outra tag usando JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Eu tenho um jQuery que eu uso em um site que eu estou fazendo que aplica o efeito de zoom em uma imagem. Só que quando eu passo o mouse em cima da imagem e ele aplica o zoom, o jQuery cria uma outra tag IMG com a mesma imagem aplicando uma class="zoomImg" nela:

Só que eu estou querendo mapear esta imagem, então eu usei um código JavaScript na qual quando ao passar o mouse em cima desta imagem que está dentro de uma SPAN com um id="ex1", ela cria uma tag MAP nesta SPAN:

```
var para = document.createElement('map');
para.setAttribute('name', 'crateria-map');
document.getElementById('ex1').appendChild(para);
mostra = function() { /* Não faz nada */ } ---> este código eu obtive em outra pergunta, pois a função estava fazendo a tag ser criada toda vez que eu passava o mouse na imagem.
```

Sendo que como eu vou mapear esta imagem, eu preciso adicionar uma tag SPAN dentro desta tag SPAN que foi criada e usando o mesmo código eu não estou conseguindo:

```
var sub = document.createElement('area');
sub.setAttribute('class', 'html5lightbox');
document.getElementByName('crateria-map').appendChild(sub);
```

Na tag MAP eu usei como referencia o id="ex1" da span para adicionar a tag, então eu pensei em usar o name da tag SPAN para adicionar a tag AREA, mas como eu disse, não funcionou, eu estou usando uma "function mostra()" para ativar o JavaScript.

Espero que tenha sido claro e se não estou sendo, peço desculpas, pois não entendo quase nada de JavaScript.

Comment: Já tentou dar um `para.appendChild(sub);` e, depois, dar um append no pai de para?

Comment: Não existe `getElementByName` só no plural e dá uma array... testa `document.getElementsByName('crateria-map')[0]`

Comment: Tens essas linhas no mesmo escopo? nesse caso bastaria `para.appendChild(sub); ` em vez de `document.getElementByName('crateria-map').appendChild(sub); `

Comment: Felipe, parece que deu certo a sua resposta document.getElementsByName('crateria-map')[0] mas eu vou verificar se está tudo certo mesmo.

Comment: Felipe, deu certo, obrigado pela ajuda, seria bom teu colocar estas informações como resposta para eu poder marca-la, mas vlw mesmo!

Comment: @MarceloLinsdeCarvalho [neste teu comment](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/55411/adicionar-uma-tag-em-outra-tag-usando-javascript/55421?noredirect=1#comment113628_55411) referiste a minha solução com o nome "Felipe", eu sou o Sérgio. Qual das ideias usaste?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Em JavaScript não existe `getElementByName` só no plural `getElementsByName` e vai retornar uma array.

Assim se só existe um elemento podes ir buscar o primeiro elemento dessa array com `document.getElementsByName('crateria-map')[0].appendChild(sub);`.

Olhando para o teu código pergunto-me se essas linhas estão na mesma função. Pois nesse caso ainda fica mais simples, não precisas de ia procurar no DOM e podes usar somente `para.appendChild(sub);`. O código todo seria:

```
var para = document.createElement('map');
para.setAttribute('name', 'crateria-map');
document.getElementById('ex1').appendChild(para);

// assumindo que estas linhas estão no mesmo escopo/função
var sub = document.createElement('area');
sub.setAttribute('class', 'html5lightbox');
para.appendChild(sub);
```

Comment: estão na mesma função sim sergio, mas estou verificando a resposta do felipe, vendo se está tudo certo aqui, mas vou tentar desta forma também, obrigado

Comment: Sergio, por enquanto vou ficar com a solução do felipe, mas qualquer coisa se achar melhor modifico para a sua, obrigado também pela ajuda.

Comment: kkkkk, foi vc que mandou, desculpe, vo marca-lo, eu acabei me confundindo...